# How do I display the full column?

Tags: python, pandas

```
missingval= data.isnull().sum()

missingval
Unnamed: 0           0
ID                   0
Name                 0
Age                  0
Photo                0
                  ... 
GKHandling          48
GKKicking           48
GKPositioning       48
GKReflexes          48
Release Clause    1564
Length: 89, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in Pandas that controls this:

```
import pandas as pd


pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)
missingval = data.isnull().sum()

missingval
```

This should then display all of the rows.

More detailed information on the available options can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html). Specific ones of interest could be:

```
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)
pd.set_option("display.width", None)
pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth", -1)
```

These would stop truncation of the columns.